# FFMPEG - why do I end up with old version after installing?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, whm

I managed to install FFMPEG on Centos via WHM following [this guide](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos).

But when I run `ffmpeg -version` I get:

2.8.15

...whereas the official site says the latest version is 4.0.2.

How can I update my installation or install afresh with the latest version?

(Context: I'm trying to work out why a WEBM-to-MP4 conversion via FFMPEG results in a 0-bytes file and thought updating FFMPEG might help.)

Comment: The Nux Desktop repository used in the guide must not have the latest version of FFMPEG. You can request an update on [their forums](https://forums.nux.ro/). [via](https://li.nux.ro/repos.html)

Comment: Share full log of the ffmpeg cmd

Comment: Note also, the maintainer of the Nux Desktop repository [suggests](https://forums.nux.ro/index.php?t=msg&th=521&goto=3824&S=b5e9c06b7b182d3f443f3bc21e2f9f4b#msg_3824) installing from [binaries built from git source](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However installing stuff on a server is not something I know anything about. Is it possible to "install from binaries" from within CPanel WHM? I don't have access to the physical server, just WHM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the Nux Dextop repo. It currently only provides the FFmpeg 2.8 release branch and older (I simply viewed the [package directory](http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/)).

1. Uninstall the old `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   sudo yum remove ffmpeg
   ```
2. Remove that repository (optional but recommended). I'll leave that up to you.
3. Download the new `ffmpeg`. No need for a repo as the pre-compiled binary is sufficient.

   ```
   curl -OL https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
   ```
4. Extract it:

   ```
   tar xvf ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
   ```
5. Copy or move the `ffmpeg` file to a location in your `PATH` so it is executable to all users (the date in this example is just a placeholder as it changes depending on when it was compiled):

   ```
   sudo cp ffmpeg-git-20181103-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin
   ```
6. Verify that you are running a recent version by running the `ffmpeg` command. The first line should look something like:

   ```
   ffmpeg version N-92330-gd6d407d2d7 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
   ```

   ...where the `d6d407d2d7` (minus the often confusing and annoying `g` prefix) is the partial hash of the [particular commit](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=d6d407d2d7) that this `ffmpeg` was derived from in the master branch.

See [What is a static build and how do I install it?](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I got as far as step 5, which errors. "cannot stat ‘ffmpeg-git-20181103-64bit-static/ffmpeg’: No such file or directory". Everything had gone great up to that point.

Comment: Ah, that seems to be because the resultant tar unzipping produced `20181101`, not `20181103` as in your command

Comment: Great - all installed. Though it seems harder to infer version number than with the old one; if I run `ffmpeg -version` I get `ffmpeg version N-47330-g4a976200d7-static` - how do you interpret version from that? :)

Comment: @Utkanos The date in my command was just an example as the date changes per build. As for the version, because you are using a build from the git master branch, you will have to go with the commit hash number and view it via `git log` or git-web ([example for 4a976200d7](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=4a976200d7)). Releases are always way behind current development: they are intended for distributors or those who need to stay within a specific major version for API compatibility.